# Android sqlite in Services

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, android-multidex

I'm using sqlite in my app. It works fine, but in services it not works, and I receive the error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

my code:

```
public class LocalServiceWakeUp extends Service {

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Query the database and show alarm if it applies
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper. getReadableDatabase();

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM " +
                    DataEntry.DbEntry.TABLE_NAME + " " +
                    "ORDER BY " + DataEntry.DbEntry._ID + " ASC";

            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sqLiteDatabase , ql);
    }
}
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DataEntry.DbEntry.DATABASE_NAME, null, DataEntry.DbEntry.DATABASE_VERSION);

DbHelper.context = context;
}
```

I think that the problem is on context, If I try to print the conext I see:

```
android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication@8cd270b
```

How to resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The code you posted does not seem to be valid - how far is it from your actual code? In particular, are you opening your database when initialising service field values?

Comment: Do you have your service running in different process?

Comment: Do not hold context in static variables, that's a memory leak and also could be the root of your problem.

Comment: Yes, i'm opening the db when initializing service. This code works fine on activity (I open the db in oncreate function). How to change the code? When I need to open the db? @viktor yes, I run the service with receiver

Comment: I'm not using context in static variabile, I'm using getapplicationcontext() function

Comment: `DbHelper.context = context;`

Comment: the problem is not on DbHelper.context = context;, I've tried to remove it and the problem is the same android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Answer (score 0):

In DbHelper class use this:

```
public Cursor getAllAlarms() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(SQL_SELECT_ALL_ALARMS, null);
    return res;
}
```

Create a class to help yourself on these methods:

```
public class AlarmHelper {

public static ArrayList<Alarm> getAlarmsFromDatabase(Context context) {
    ArrayList<Alarm> alarms = new ArrayList<>();
    FeedReaderDbHelper myDb = new FeedReaderDbHelper(context);
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllAlarms();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
            alarm.setId(cursor.getString(0));
            alarm.setTime(cursor.getString(1));
            alarm.setStatus(cursor.getString(2));
            alarms.add(alarm);
        }
    }
    myDb.close();
    return alarms;
}
```

So, on your service you will have only this to get your alarms:

```
public class LocalServiceWakeUp extends Service {

  private Context context;

  public AlarmService() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      context = getApplicationContext();
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      ArrayList<Alarm> alarms = AlarmHelper.getAlarmsFromDatabase(context);

      //TODO YOUR CODE HERE

  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is on manifest. I've added 2 line on service tag android:isolatedProcess="true"
android:stopWithTask="false", without this line it works. But how to keep alive the service afert the app is killed?

Comment: right, did you try to leave the mainfest with only this? <service
android:name=".services.LocalService" /> I assume that you are killing the context so it can not access your getApplicationContext() method when it is destroyed. Have you tried to use Firebase Database? Its works offline too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on Manifest.
I've added

```
android:isolatedProcess="true"
android:stopWithTask="false"
```

on serivice tag:

```
<service
android:name=".services.LocalService"
android:enabled="true"
android:isolatedProcess="true"
android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

If I remove the row android:isolatedProcess and android:stopWithTask it works, but If I kill the app, alse the service is killed.

How to resolve the problem? My question is, how to keep alive the service after the app is killed?

Thanks a lot